# How do I pass the link anchor text

Tags: javascript, forms, syntax, anchor, hyperlink

I'm new to Javascript and I've asked several of my Javascript friends and they don't seem to have an answer. I've been developing a simple search query in PHP and it outputs several results for example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="injectForm(this);">Result Text Here</a>
<a href="#" onclick="injectForm(this);">Result Text 2 Here</a>
<a href="#" onclick="injectForm(this);">Result Text 3 Here</a>


<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<label for="textfield"></label>
<input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />Search
</form>
```

pseudocode for injectForm();

- grab the .value of the link that was just clicked
- pass that into variable  i.e.  result = (something something).value
- set form1.textfield.value = result

What I'd like to do is have a simple injectForm() function that reads the value of the result "Anchor Text Here" so when someone clicks on it - it drops the value "Result Text Here" it into the "textfield" in the form.  I believe you can do this with DOM - I do NOT want to use any JS libraries such as Jquery.

Anyone have ideas?  If I used a different DIV or SPAN tag for each href you could use DOM - i'd like to not have to number each result with a different div or class if possible - just reading the relative this(); kind of thingy.

Comment: yes. I've read a book on javascript and it always refers to the DOM model with specific div or ID tags. I'm trying to better understand the 'this();' function - so to try to write the function without understanding this(); would be pointless. I'll start on it if that's what you want to see.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple

```js
document.getElementById("injectDiv").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("inject")) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel link
    document.getElementById("textfield").value = tgt.innerHTML;
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="injectDiv">
  <a href="#" class="inject">Result Text 1 Here</a><br/>
  <a href="#" class="inject">Result Text 2 Here</a><br/>
  <a href="#" class="inject">Result Text 3 Here</a><br/></div>
<input type="text" id="textfield" />
```

Older inline version

```js
function injectForm(theLink) {
  document.getElementById("textfield").value = theLink.innerHTML;
  return false; // cancel the click
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="return injectForm(this);">Result Text 1 Here</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="return injectForm(this);">Result Text 2 Here</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="return injectForm(this);">Result Text 3 Here</a>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textfield" />
```

Comment: It worked! That is simply the fastest response I've ever had! Thank you thank you!